# How does Calcite deal with data conversion?

Tags: sql, apache-beam, apache-calcite, beam-sql

I am trying to convert a date that's stored as a string to a date, e.g.

YYYYMMDD (string) to YYYY-MM-DD (date)

As far as I know there is no conversion function that checks input format and output format, I tried manual logic, e.g.

```
CASE 
  WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(some_string_date)) = 8
  THEN
    CAST(
      SUBSTRING(TRIM(some_string_date) FROM 1 FOR 4)
      || '-'
      || SUBSTRING(TRIM(some_string_date) FROM 5 FOR 2)
      ||'-'
      || SUBSTRING(TRIM(some_string_date) FROM 7 FOR 2)
    as DATE) 
  ELSE
    NULL 
END
```

However this is not accepted by Apache SQL Validator, does anyone see problem here?

Comment: Based on the tags, are you using Beam SQL?

Comment: Yes, I am providing sql that should be compliant with Calcite Grammar (Calcite Grammar is used by Apache Beam SQL).

Comment: calcite is considering adding date format support. We can vote this issue.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-2980

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answering the question, but maybe related, date literals are declared with `DATE` keyword, e.g. you can see examples in the tests in Beam tests: [one](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b06e28bf9605f232c270993728361bd0fc2ee08a/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/BeamSqlDslSqlStdOperatorsTest.java#L559), [two](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/bdd0081b49f8e7df6733dc8e8bc90dda3efc6621/sdks/java/extensions/sql/jdbc/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/jdbc/BeamSqlLineTest.java#L90) and in Calcite [docs](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#scalar-types).

**Update:**

What seems to happen is Calcite adds some indirection when doing `CASE`. Casting the strings to dates works as expected in general. For example, if  input rows have schema `(INT f_int, VARCHAR f_string)` and dates are in `'YYYYMMDD'` (e.g. `(1, '2018')`, then this works:

```
SELECT f_int,
   CAST(
    SUBSTRING(TRIM(f_string) FROM 1 FOR 4)
      ||'-'
      ||SUBSTRING(TRIM(f_string) FROM 5 FOR 2)
      ||'-'
      ||SUBSTRING(TRIM(f_string) FROM 7 FOR 2) as DATE)
  FROM PCOLLECTION
```

Even directly casting the `'YYYYMMDD'` works:

```
SELECT f_int,
   CAST(f_string AS DATE)
FROM PCOLLECTION
```

You can see all supported date formats [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/06128f27d1780f25c23ca65cc7ace693a78dac80/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/impl/interpreter/operator/BeamSqlCastExpression.java#L45).

But as soon as you wrap it in `'CASE ... ELSE NULL'`, then Beam/Calcite seem to infer that the expression type is now a `'String'`. This means that  `'THEN CAST(... AS DATE)'` succeeds and returns a 'Date', but then it's converted to `'String'` when wrapped in `'CASE'`. Then, when returning the result in my test it seems to try to cast it back to `'Date'`, but the string format now is not `'YYYYMMDD'` but some other default format. Unfortunately that format is not in the list of supported, so it fails.

**Workaround:**

As soon as you change `'ELSE NULL'` to something that's known to be a `'Date'`, e.g. `'ELSE DATE "2001-01-01"'` then it works again as Beam/Calcite don't seem to go though `'String'->'Date'->'String'->'Date'` path and this works:

```
SELECT f_int,
  CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(f_string)) = 8
    THEN CAST (
       SUBSTRING(TRIM(f_string) FROM 1 FOR 4)
       ||'-'
       ||SUBSTRING(TRIM(f_string) FROM 5 FOR 2)
       ||'-'
       ||SUBSTRING(TRIM(f_string) FROM 7 FOR 2) AS DATE)
    ELSE DATE '2001-01-01'
  END
FROM PCOLLECTION
```

I filed [BEAM-5789](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5789) to track a better solution.

**Update 2:**

So, while Calcite generates the plan telling Beam what to do, it's Beam that actually casts/parses the dates in this case. There's an effort to use Calcite's built-in implementations of basic operations instead of re-implementing everything in Beam:
https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/6417 . After this pull request is merged, this `CASE ... ELSE NULL` path should work automatically, if I'm reading it right (I assume [this class](https://github.com/apache/calcite-avatica/blob/3cfafde9f5f0f1fc3ddc60b5a4db19762c73b96b/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/avatica/util/DateTimeUtils.java#L374) will be used for handling date/time values). It will still go through strings, probably unnecessarily, but it should just work.

Comment: Thanks for reference! The issue here was not the syntax itself, but `TRIM` function. Apache Calcite is case sensitive so `trim` and `TRIM` are different.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you mean that by using `trim` instead of `TRIM` everything works for you?

Comment: Yes :) Calcite doc says keywords are case sensitive, however doesn't say which of them, so far I am aware of that one only.

Comment: Oh, nice find. Looks like there are two issues here then :)

Answer (score -2):

If is MYSQL.
You may try

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('20080908', '%Y%m%d'), "%Y-%m-%d");
```

For validate, you may check whether the string could be converted to date successfully. sometimes. NULL means failed.